# Unexpected EOF while parsing with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I execute the following function:

```
def multi_joueurs():
    global liste_des_joueurs
    liste_des_joueurs=[]

def  nombre_des_joueurs():
    fen2305=Tk()
    fen2305.title("un seul joueur")
    fen2305.config(bg='royalblue')
    label=Label(fen2305,text="nombre des joueurs dans ce matche:")
    global nobre_jouer
    nobre_joer=Entry(fen2305)
    botn=Button(fen2305,text="valider")
    label.grid()
    nobre_joer.grid()
    botn.grid()
    nobre_jouer=nobre_joer.get()
    ferme(fen2305)
    fen2305.mainloop()


def ouvre(m):
    fen23055=Tk()
    fen23055.title("un seul joueur")
    fen23055.config(bg='royalblue')
    label=Label(fen23055,text="donner le nom du joueur "+str(m)+":")
    nom_joueur=Entry(fen23055)

    label.grid()
    nom_joueur.grid()

    def va():
        global nom_pre_joueur
        nom_pre_joueur=nom_joueur.get()
        if nom_pre_joueur!='':
            fen23055.destroy()
    botn=Button(fen23055,text="valider",command=va)
    botn.grid()
    fen23055.mainloop()



def nom_des_joueurs():
    for m in range(int(eval(nobre_jouer))):
        ouvre(nobre_jouer)
        liste_des_joueurs.append(str(nom_pre_joueur))


nombre_des_joueurs()
nom_des_joueurs()
```

But here is the error:

```
, line 4, in nom_des_joueurs
    for m in range(int(eval(nobre_jouer))):
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: What is in the variable `nobre_jouer` ?

Comment: The above code does not give that error. You are missing imports. When you fix the missing import you get another error. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The first step in debugging this is to verify that `nombre_jouer` is what you are assuming it is. Have you done that? What is in that variable immediately before calling `eval`?